# Bicep to create nsg and nsg security rules

Tags: azure-bicep

I have just converted an existing resource in Azure to bicep, currently trying to rewrite it such that the code will create the nsg and use a json template file to loop through the security rules.

Somewhat confused from the research that I have done, and not sure if this is possible to do. The idea is to have a parameter file in json where all the rules are defined, then a module to create the security rules by looping through them and assign to the nsg.

Found the link here but the solution appears incomplete. see https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/5849

```
resource networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2023-06-01' = {
  name: networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name
  location: 'WestEurope'
  properties: {
    securityRules: [
      {
        name: 'AllowOnPremToAzure'
        id: networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_AllowOnPremToAzure.id
        type: 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules'
        properties: {
          protocol: '*'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          destinationPortRange: '*'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '12.0.0.0/24'
          destinationAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
          access: 'Allow'
          priority: 1000
          direction: 'Inbound'
          sourcePortRanges: []
          destinationPortRanges: []
          sourceAddressPrefixes: []
          destinationAddressPrefixes: []
        }
      }
      {
        name: 'AllowAzureToOnPrem'
        id: networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_AllowAzureToOnPrem.id
        type: 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules'
        properties: {
          protocol: '*'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          destinationPortRange: '*'
          sourceAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '12.0.0.0/24'
          access: 'Allow'
          priority: 1000
          direction: 'Outbound'
          sourcePortRanges: []
          destinationPortRanges: []
          sourceAddressPrefixes: []
          destinationAddressPrefixes: []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}




################


resource networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_AllowAzureToOnPrem 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules@2023-06-01' = {
  name: '${networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name}/AllowAzureToOnPrem'
  properties: {
    protocol: '*'
    sourcePortRange: '*'
    destinationPortRange: '*'
    sourceAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
    destinationAddressPrefix: '12.0.0.0/24'
    access: 'Allow'
    priority: 1000
    direction: 'Outbound'
    sourcePortRanges: []
    destinationPortRanges: []
    sourceAddressPrefixes: []
    destinationAddressPrefixes: []
  }
  dependsOn: [
    networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_resource
  ]
}

resource networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_AllowOnPremToAzure 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules@2023-06-01' = {
  name: '${networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name}/AllowOnPremToAzure'
  properties: {
    protocol: '*'
    sourcePortRange: '*'
    destinationPortRange: '*'
    sourceAddressPrefix: '12.0.0.0/24'
    destinationAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
    access: 'Allow'
    priority: 1000
    direction: 'Inbound'
    sourcePortRanges: []
    destinationPortRanges: []
    sourceAddressPrefixes: []
    destinationAddressPrefixes: []
  }
  dependsOn: [
    networkSecurityGroups_nsg_uat_001_name_resource
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nsg.bicep`

```
param nsgName string = 'nsgtest'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param securityRules array

resource networkSecurityGroup 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2022-01-01' = {
  name: nsgName
  location: location
  properties: {
    securityRules: securityRules
  }
}
```

`nsg_param.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "securityRules": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "rule1",
                "properties": {
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "sourcePortRange": "*",
                  "destinationPortRange": "443",
                  "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                  "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                  "access": "Allow",
                  "priority": 100,
                  "direction": "Inbound"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "rule2",
                "properties": {
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "sourcePortRange": "*",
                  "destinationPortRange": "80",
                  "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                  "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                  "access": "Allow",
                  "priority": 101,
                  "direction": "Inbound"
                }
            }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

no need to loop but treated as a whole array.

Answer (score 0):

The NSG itself. This is just an example

```
param nsgName string
param location string
param date string 
param email string


resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-05-01' = {
  name: nsgName
  location: location
  tags: {
    CreatedOn: date
    Owner: email
  }
  properties: {}   
}
```

---

Rules

```
param nsgName string

var dir = 'Inbound'

resource nsgRule4000 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules@2021-05-01' = {
  name: '${nsgName}/IN_VNET_Deny'
  properties: {
    access: 'Deny'
    description: 'Deny default VNET traffic'
    destinationAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
    destinationPortRange: '*'
    direction: dir
    priority: 4000
    protocol: '*'
    sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
    sourcePortRange: '*'
  }
}

resource nsgRule3000 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules@2021-05-01' = {
  name: '${nsgName}/IN_Ping_ALLOW'
  properties: {
    access: 'Allow'
    description: 'Allow PING from VNET'
    destinationAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
    destinationPortRange: '*'
    direction: dir
    priority: 3000
    protocol: 'Icmp'
    sourceAddressPrefix: 'VirtualNetwork'
    sourcePortRange: '*'
  }
}
```

---

See also here
https://github.com/wedoazure/blogAZNet/tree/main/NSG